# Get MAX value of each record in group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL looks like that:

```
 select fldCustomer, fldTerminal, COUNT(fldbill)
 from tblDataBills
 group by fldCustomer, fldTerminal
 order by fldCustomer
```

results looks like:

```
 fldCustomer    fldTerminal (number of bills)
 0  1   19086
 0  2   10
 0  5   236
 1  1   472
 1  5   3
 1  500 19
 2  1   292
 2  500 22
```

how can i get the MAX count of each customer so i get results like

```
 0 1 19086
 1 1 472
 2 1 292
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery with `row_number()`:

```
select fldCustomer, fldTerminal, cnt
from (select fldCustomer, fldTerminal, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by fldCustomer order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from tblDataBills
      group by fldCustomer, fldTerminal
     ) db
where seqnum = 1
order by fldCustomer ;
```

Note that in the event of ties, this will arbitrarily return one of the rows.  If you want all of them, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Comment: @Liroy you have to accept this answer, just click on the mark below the voting arrows that are found beside of this answer

Answer (score 1):

This might require a little trickery with the `RANK()` function

```
SELECT fldCustomer, fldTerminal, [(number of bills)]
FROM (
    SELECT fldCustomer, fldTerminal, COUNT(fldbill) [(number of bills)],
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fldCustomer ORDER BY COUNT(fldbill) DESC) Ranking
    FROM tblDataBills
    GROUP BY fldCustomer, fldTerminal
) a
WHERE Ranking = 1
```